# How to spawn rebel citizen medic?

Tags: cheats, half-life-2

In Half-Life 2 the console command `npc_create npc_citizen` spawns a rebel citizen. is there a cheat to spawn a rebel medic?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify existing citizens to become medics after you've already spawned them.

---

**To make and individual citizen a medic:**

Mouseover them with the crosshair and enter `ent_fire !picker setmedicon` into the console.

---

**To make all citizens medics:**

Optionally, spawn new citizen(s):
`npc_create npc_citizen`

Toggle them to all be medics: `ent_fire npc_citizen setmedicon`

---

**To toggle groups of citizens to be medics, or to toggle individual citizens to be medics without mousing over them**:

You can assign citizens (or individual citizens) to custom groups when you spawn them: `npc_create npc_citizen whatever_group_name_you_want`

This allows you to easily modify specific citizens that you've spawned: `ent_fire whatever_group_name_you_want setmeticon`

Alternate example: `npc_create npc_citizen medics` `ent_fire medics setmedicon`

Another example: `npc_create npc_citizen jack` `ent_fire jack setmedicon`

---

For a full list of commands, look here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Npc_citizen#Inputs

Or, in game type `ent_info npc_citizen` into your console for a full list of possible inputs.

Note that you may need to enter `sv_cheats 1` prior to running some commands to get them to function.

---

Finally, **quicksave** and then type `ent_fire npc_citizen ignite`. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found a way; it's very simple:

- Rebel medic: `ent_create npc_citizen citizentype 3 spawnflags 393732 additionalequipment weapon_smg1`
- Rebel standard: `ent_create npc_citizen citizentype 3 spawnflags 262660 additionalequipment weapon_smg1`

There you go! Have fun:)